# Restrict number of concurrent builds per user in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there an easy way to restrict the number of allowed concurrent builds per user in Jenkins? What I'm trying to do is to make the queuing a bit more fair and stop one user from submitting many many jobs.

Ideally I'm looking for a solution that would work with the new jenkins pipeline interface as well.

Comment: How about disabling concurrent builds in Jenkins configuration

Comment: I do want concurrent builds, I want to maintain fairness across users. Maybe this plugin does it for me: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin

Comment: Why do you want to restrict concurrent builds? To me that sounds like either you have not enough resources (VMs) running to build what needs to be built or you have some user(s) using Jenkins just for fun. Usually if the users need to build something they should be able to do so. However how about just reserving a certain amount of VMs per User/Project using labels?

Comment: Well, we're using (absuing?) Jenkins as a job queuing solution for multiple GPUs across multiple nodes. Let's say we have 2 nodes each with 4 GPUs and we're sharing them between 12 people. Our jobs take hours or even days to finish. It's totally ok for one person to have 100 pending jobs in the queue but when someone else puts a new job in the queue I want it to go to the head of the queue. Well, not exactly the head but I don't want it to wait for 100 jobs to finish.